# Nginx how does directory location matching works when two blocks of similar location is provided?

Tags: nginx-config

I have a nginx location blocks in this order:

```
location ~* example\.js {
            if_modified_since off;
            expires off;
            etag off;
            add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        }

        location ~* \.js$ {
            expires 7d;
            add_header "Cache-Control" "public, no-transform";
        }
```

I want the cache of example to be `no-cache` and for all other js files cache to be for 7 days.

Is this configuration that I wrote correct or should I change the order? How does the preference work and specificity wise both of them appear same to me.

I don't want the `exmaple.js` file to fall through to the second condition.